# SQL Server not using non clustered index

Tags: sql-server, indexing, relational-database, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have table where the `PK` is a `Guid` (clustered index) and `Name` (string, non clustered index) in SQL Server. Every time I run the query with the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, it only uses the clustered index and omits the non clustered index, and the names are not in ascending order too.

[image]

The query is

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(@__p_3) [c].[Id],  [c].[Name]
FROM [Company] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND (CASE
    WHEN [c].[Name] >= @__p_0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END & (CASE
    WHEN [c].[Name] > @__p_0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END | (CASE
    WHEN [c].[Name] = @__p_1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END & CASE
    WHEN [c].[Id] > @__p_2 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END))) = CAST(1 AS bit)
ORDER BY [c].[id],[c].[Name]',N'@__p_3 int,@__p_0 nvarchar(300),@__p_1 nvarchar(300),@__p_2 uniqueidentifier',@__p_3=3,@__p_0=N'Salmaan and CO',@__p_1=N'Salmaan and CO',@__p_2='04D3EEC3-2A91-42E2-3463-08DADF2F5363'
```

[image]

[image]

But when I the query making the `Name` as the first in the `ORDER BY` and then `ID`, it works and returns the expected results along with the clustered and non clustered index

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(@__p_3) [c].[Id],  [c].[Name]
FROM [Company] AS [c]
WHERE [c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND (CASE
    WHEN [c].[Name] >= @__p_0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END & (CASE
    WHEN [c].[Name] > @__p_0 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END | (CASE
    WHEN [c].[Name] = @__p_1 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END & CASE
    WHEN [c].[Id] > @__p_2 THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END))) = CAST(1 AS bit)
ORDER BY [c].[Name],[c].[id]',N'@__p_3 int,@__p_0 nvarchar(300),@__p_1 nvarchar(300),@__p_2 uniqueidentifier',@__p_3=3,@__p_0=N'Salmaan and CO',@__p_1=N'Salmaan and CO',@__p_2='04D3EEC3-2A91-42E2-3463-08DADF2F5363'
```

[image]

[image]

The problem with the second approach is it has a higher execution cost even the data is correct. The first query has less cost, but the data is wrong as the `ORDER BY` on `Name` is not applied. Please help

Comment: How are you determining *cost*? I hope you're not relying on the SQL Server estimated cost as second-hand toilet paper is more useful. Have you actually measured the performance?

Comment: I have run tests, the second query is 10 times slower than the first one and i used the profiler in the ssms which is built  in

Comment: So - do you prefer a *wrong* result quickly - or the *correct* result a bit more slowly ? Your choice ...

Comment: @marc_s, i will go for the correct result but its 10 times slower, but why is the first query not working as expected?

Comment: Why do you expect ordering by `ID` before `Name` would ***not*** make a difference?  You want the first 3 rows ***based upon*** that ordering.   A different order would give a different set of rows, so the optimiser will attempt to scan the index what has an order closest to the `ORDER BY` of your query, unless there is another consideration that would become more costly because of that choice...  For your second query, the best index would be `company(IsDeleted, Name, ID)` or also cover the columns used by the query, so as not to need to look at the table at all.

Comment: @MatBailie, i understand that. But once i order by id and then name it has to give the same result isnt it?

Comment: Order these 3 rows by `(id, name)` and give me the 1st row, then order them by `(name,id)` and give me the 1st row.  Hint; they don't give the same result!  `id=1, Name='Z'` , `id=2, Name='Y'` , `id=3, Name='X'`.  Ordering by `(id,name)` will return `id=1, Name='Z'`, but ordering by `(name,id)` will return `id=3, Name='X'`.

Comment: And what's with you casting to BITs, doing bitwise `&`, etc?  Just do this...  `WHERE [c].[IsDeleted] = CAST(0 AS bit) AND ( [c].[Name] >= @__p_0 AND [c].[Name] > @__p_0 OR [c].[Name] = @__p_1 AND [c].[Id] > @__p_2 )`  Just make sure you have the brackets in the right places.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this article. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/ It goes into depth about why using a guid a clustered index is not a great idea.

Comment: @MatBailie it's probably autogenerated code from some framework

Comment: @thanzeel You have a WHERE ID > {some guid param} , are you sure it's actually doing what you think it's doing? Usually GUIDs aren't sorted (unless you use sequentialGUIDs)

Comment: @siggemannen, this code was generated by ef core 7.

Comment: @siggemannen , im using this to do Keyset pagination. its working as expected, yes im aware its not a good idea to sort by guid